# Eclipse Folder Structure

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

my Workspace on Eclipse is currently set-up so that it has a Folder Structure, like this:[image]

I made it like that on accident but I prefer to use it and I need to make a new Workspace soon, because I don't want to delete all my projects.

Does anyone know how to make Eclipse be set-up like this with a folder structure instead of like this:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the small down arrow (triangle) at the top right of the view and select 'Package Presentation > Hierarchical' in the menu that appears.